# TDD for Systems Programs

Tags: c++, tdd

I am trying to practice TDD while writing a program that uses syscalls to write code into another processes' memory, e.g the equivalent Windows API calls would be something like:

```
CreateProcess(...);
VirtualAllocEx(...);
WriteProcessMemory(...);
CreateRemoteThread(...);
```

I'm struggling to come up with what the first test would be, as there isn't much logic, in addition to actually writing the code in a testable way.

I set off with creating a class around the syscalls then just mocking it and verifying that the expected functions are called, but it felt like I was just adding abstraction layers for the sake of testing and the tests themselves did little but verify that the calls were made.

None of the *actual* functionality, i.e. the syscalls themselves, writing memory etc was being tested.

Am I just trying to test something with too little logic? Or that where the real testable content lies in a tough place to test (i.e. syscalls interacting with the OS)?

Comment: In one of my TDD-style unit tests, I'm checking the logic for when after an hour passes, an event happens.  My MockClock does not actually wait an entire hour, rather it is set up with a count of how many time checks happen before the clock returns back that an hour has passed.  The unit test takes moments to run (rather than an hour).  C++ may be a bit more unwieldy, but the same concept should apply.  (My TDD unit tests were with Visual Studio, C#, ReSharper, NUnit, NCrunch -- awesome toolset for TDD.)

Comment: Thanks for the response! I understand the advantage of mocking, but in my case I feel I'm adding abstraction layers just to test then mocking out *all* the content until the test just checks that four or five functions are invoked in order and that's all. As I'm not writing a test that checks "and process X is opened and memory is allocated" technically if I'm following TDD I'm never going to write that logic, right? And if I add the logic anyway it's not going to be tested...

Comment: What you are trying to test may not be very amenable to unit testing.  Perhaps a unit test that just checks 5 functions are called in order is all it can do, and defer to integration testing or system testing to verify that these parts of your code do actually work properly together.  (Unit tests are not a replacement for integration testing or system testing.  And vice versa, integration testing and system testing are not a substitute for unit testing.)

Comment: This is indeed where my mind's going, just not done TDD for a long time so wasn't sure if I was missing something. Thanks for the input :)

Answer (score 1):

> Am I just trying to test something with too little logic?

Perhaps.  If the code you are trying to write is "so simple that there are obviously no deficiencies", then having a bunch of automated mistake detectors isn't going to buy you very much.

On the other hand, something needs to decide which syscall to make next, and what the arguments are supposed to be, and how to handle contingencies.  As the complexity of that piece grows, the benefit of automated mistake detectors grows.

My guess: if you write your core logic using function pointers, and pass the various syscalls as arguments to your core logic, you'll have a clean enough separation of concerns that you can defer the introduction of tests until later.

When is later?  Either when you start receiving feedback that the core logic has not-obvious deficiencies, or if you feeling like the cost of making changes safely is beginning to offset what you would need to invest in tests.

It may also make sense at that point to create a new implementation of the core logic from scratch, using tests.